Autodesk Platform Services - How to get address from `locationsContainerId`
This is related to Autodesk Platform Services API (previously called Forge).
I have the locationsContainerId of a project, I want to find out its actual location. Previously the project info contained fields like address_line_1, city... but it no longer did.
I found this endpoint but apparently it's wrong (returns 404):
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/docs/v1/projects/${projectId}/containers/${locationsContainerId}/locations
So how do I get address information from projectId and locationsContainerId? What's the correct endpoint currently?
